# Generate all possible permutations for 2 vectors

Tags: matlab, permutation

I was wondering if there was a way to generate all possible permutations for 2 vectors. I know that I can use perms, but that just works for one vector.

What I would like is to input the vector [1 2 3]
and would get out

```
V1 = []      V2 = [1 2 3]
V1 = [1 2 3] V2 = []
V1 = [1]     V2 = [2 3]
V1 = [2]     V2 = [1 3]
...
```

Also could I store all of these permutations in a cell array becuase they all have different lengths so a Matrix won't work.

Comment: do you need all permutations or all possible divisions? that is do you need `[1],[ 2 3 ]` as well as `[1], [ 3 2 ]`, or one of these two will suffice?

Comment: Yeah I just need one of these too. Sorry I should have clarrified that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
output = {};
v = [1 2 3];  % input
N = length(v);
for k=1:2^N
    m = logical( bitget(k, 1:N) );  % mask selecting elements of v1
    v1 = v(m);
    v2 = v(~m);
    output{end+1} = {v1, v2};
end
```

Comment: Well, for my version (2014a) `bitget` returns doubles, you can't directly use for indexing. I edited that line to make your code more robust. Weird that it works for you, what version you have?

Comment: Ha OK, I'm on octave, not matlab, my bad :)

Comment: ah okay! For a vectorized version of your answer, see the edit of my answer. Don't think its faster though, it was just for fun ;)

Comment: Thanks so much @thewaywewalk and seb. You guys were really helpful! I also have an old version of matlab so bitget returned doubles, but the clumsy one worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In almost one line, the credit should go to [seb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24890201/2605073) though.

```
v = [1 2 3 4]; 
N = numel(v);

out = cellfun(@(x) {v(x) v(~x)}, mat2cell( logical( bsxfun(@bitget,(1:2^N)', (1:N)) ) ,ones(1,2^N),N) , 'uni', 0)
```

---

My old answer, clumsy, but works:

```
A = arrayfun(@(x) nchoosek(V,x), 1:numel(V), 'uni',0);
B = cellfun(@(x) mat2cell(x,ones(1,size(x,1)),size(x,2)),A,'uni',0);

V1 = vertcat({[]},B{:});
V2 = cellfun(@(x) setdiff(V,x), V1, 'uni',0);
```

gives:

```
>> celldisp(V1)

V1{1} =
     []
V1{2} =
     1
V1{3} =
     2
V1{4} =
     3
V1{5} =
     1     2
V1{6} =
     1     3
V1{7} =
     2     3
V1{8} =
     1     2     3
```

and for `V2` right the opposite.

Comment: Is there anyway to scale this up so that it could generate all permutations of one vector into 3 or 4 vectors as well? @thewaywewalk

Comment: @AustenNovis not with this approach.

Comment: any tips on how one would start something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

```
a=num2cell(1:3);
output1=cellfun(@(x) nchoosek(1:3,x),a,'UniformOutput',false);
output_reverse=cellfun(@(x) nchoosek(3:-1:1,x),a(2:3),'UniformOutput',false);
```

For a sequence of `1,2,3`, the output would be as follows:

```
output1{1}=

     1
     2
     3

output1{2}=

     1     2
     1     3
     2     3

output1{3}=

     1     2     3
```

Execute the `output_reverse` line only when you require the reverse combinations also. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop over all possible divisions. For each division, compute a mask (logical index) that tells which elements go to `V1` and which go to `V2`. The following assumes order is not important, i.e. `[1],[2 3]` is the same division as `[1], [3 2]`.

```
vector = [1 2 3]; %// example data
N = numel(vector); %// number of elements
NN = 2^N; %// number of results
V1 = cell(1,NN); %// intiallize
V2 = cell(1,NN); %// intiallize
for n = 0:NN-1;
    mask = logical(dec2bin(n,N)-'0'); %// logical index for values in V1
    V1{n+1} = vector(mask);
    V2{n+1} = vector(~mask);
end
```